# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'int'. How to remove this warning?

Tags: objective-c, ios9

```
[self logException:@"PO number check exception" withErrorCode:SYS_ERR_SALES_PO_NUMBER];
```

Answer (score 0):

write

```
int var1 = [yourstringvariable intValue];
```

or

```
int var1 = (int)yourstringvariable
```

Hope it helps.